# Where can I access a file from my oracle db with UTL_FILE?

Tags: sql, oracle, utl-file

I'm trying to read from a file with oracle db using UTL_FILE.
I can't find a file location I have access to.
Whenever I use this code:

```
DECLARE 
  F1 UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE; 
BEGIN 
  F1 :=UTL_FILE.FOPEN('C:\TEMP','test_file.txt','R'); 
END;
```

I get: ORA-29280: invalid directory path

Why would that be?

Can I somehow make oracle show the location I have access to?

BR Kresten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UTL_FILE.FOPEN` uses `DBA_DIRECTORIES`.

```
SELECT * from ALL_DIRECTORIES
```

gives you defined and accessible `DBA_DIRECTORIES`.

You can create directory for your File operations

```
CREATE DIRECTORY File_Op_Dir AS '/u01/fileDir';
GRANT READ ON DIRECTORY File_Op_Dir TO <<user>>;
--IF you need write permission 
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY File_Op_Dir TO <<user>>;
```

Then

```
 F1 := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('File_Op_Dir','u12345.tmp','R');
```